# I have issues with this XML and I want to extract ea_source name

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I want to extract the value of `ea_sourceName` and `ea_targetName` when the value of `ea_type` is `Aggregation`.

```
 <UML:Association xmi.id="EAID_018EEEB3_9A6B_4102_85C8_3A78261E9AA4" visibility="public" isRoot="false" isLeaf="false" isAbstract="false">
 <UML:ModelElement.taggedValue>
  <UML:TaggedValue tag="style" value="3" /> 
  <UML:TaggedValue tag="ea_type" value="Aggregation" /> 
  <UML:TaggedValue tag="direction" value="Source -> Destination" /> 
  <UML:TaggedValue tag="linemode" value="3" /> 
  <UML:TaggedValue tag="linecolor" value="-1" /> 
  <UML:TaggedValue tag="linewidth" value="0" /> 
  <UML:TaggedValue tag="seqno" value="0" /> 
  <UML:TaggedValue tag="headStyle" value="0" /> 
  <UML:TaggedValue tag="lineStyle" value="0" /> 
  <UML:TaggedValue tag="ea_localid" value="8" /> 
  <UML:TaggedValue tag="ea_sourceName" value="Course" /> 
  <UML:TaggedValue tag="ea_targetName" value="Sem_Progarm" /> 
  <UML:TaggedValue tag="ea_sourceType" value="Class" /> 
  <UML:TaggedValue tag="ea_targetType" value="Class" /> 
  <UML:TaggedValue tag="ea_sourceID" value="18" /> 
  <UML:TaggedValue tag="ea_targetID" value="19" /> 
  <UML:TaggedValue tag="virtualInheritance" value="0" /> 
  </UML:ModelElement.taggedValue>
```

I have tried this code, but it does not return anything. What I want is a list that contains the values of `ea_sourceName` like `Course` and so on

```
static XNamespace ns2;
ns2 = @"omg.org/UML1.3";
XDoucument MyXmiFile = XDocument.Load(path);
 string Relation = "Association";
 var q = from p in this.MyXmiFile.Descendants(ns2 + Relation)
         select p;

 var m = from p in q.Descendants(ns2 + "TaggedValue")
         where p.Attribute("tag").Value == "ea_type" && p.Attribute("value").Value == "Aggregation"
         select p;

var s = from p in m
        let P1 = p.Attribute("tag").Value
        where P1 == "ea_sourceName"
        select p.Attribute("value").Value;

List<string> Result = new List<string>(s.ToList());
```

Comment: static XNamespace ns2;
ns2 = @"omg.org/UML1.3";

Comment: this is not the Complete XML that i'm working with , this is just a sample of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there can be multiple associations that has that type, here's a query that can get them for you:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(path);
var relation = "Association";
var targetType = "Aggregation";
XNamespace UML = "omg.org/UML1.3";
var associations =
    from association in doc.Descendants(UML + relation)
    let values = association.Element(UML + "ModelElement.taggedValue")
    where ReadTaggedValue(values, "ea_type") == targetType
    select new
    {
        ea_sourceName = ReadTaggedValue(values, "ea_sourceName"),
        ea_targetName = ReadTaggedValue(values, "ea_targetName"),
    };
```

With a little helper method to read the tagged values:

```
string ReadTaggedValue(XElement values, string tag)
{
    XNamespace UML = "omg.org/UML1.3";
    return values.Elements(UML + "TaggedValue")
        .Where(e => (string)e.Attribute("tag") == tag)
        .Select(e => (string)e.Attribute("value"))
        .Single();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff for the answer , i want a list of string contains all
the ea_soureName like (Course , .. etc)

sorry to bother ^_^

Comment: when i print the value of association it is okkk , but i want the result of ea_sourceName in a list

Comment: i manipulate  the code and i convert what i want into a list
thank u so much

Answer (score 0):

Using [this xml library](https://github.com/ChuckSavage/XmlLib/), I use a XPath to get all the TaggedValue's with `tag = ea_type` and its `value = Aggregation`.  Then I create a dictionary of `<tag, value>` for each element.

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(file); // or .Parse(xmlstring)
var agg = root.XPath("//TaggedValue[@tag='ea_type' and @value={0}]", "Aggregation");
List<Dictionary<string,string>> list = agg.Select(a => a.Parent.Elements()
        .ToDictionary(b => b.Attribute("tag").Value, 
                      b => b.Attribute("value").Value))
        .ToList();
```

I made the `"Aggregation"` a parameter to the XPath method, it could have been hard-coded but I figured it may be variable.  That is up to you.

Comment: thank u
but what i want is that when the value of ea_type is Aggregation
then i want the value of "ea_source" which is "Course"
Can u do that

thanx again

Comment: I already did that.  If you run it (with the linked library) you will have it.  Aka: `list[0]["ea_source"] will equal "Course"` Presuming that there is only one with Aggregation.  If there is more, list will have each one and their respective `ea_source`